# Protect Playstation from Power outage and Surges

Tags: ps4

I live in a place where occasional power outages occur. And on experience I have had one PS3 broken after a power outage without using any UPS or AVR. Now that I will be getting a PS4, will a power supply with 325W be able to support the PS4? The UPS also has a power surge protection and may I ask will this be enough and is it a good fit for the PS4 or should I get a higher one. The brand specifically I'm planning on buying is this [APC BX625](https://www.apcc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BX625CI-MS&tab=features)
 or this one [APC BR500 CI-AS 500VA](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=br500ci-as).

Comment: I am having similar concerns as I have had 2 power surges lately and it leaves my ps4 in an odd state of bot turning on from the controller. It must first be "reset" with a press of the power button then it will power on properly.

Answer (score 3):

The highest power rating used by the PS4 that I have seen is ~150W. However, the wiki states:

> The PS4 is powered via an internal "universal" 110–240 V AC power supply, with a maximum power rating of 250 W.

[This site](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/PlayStation+4+Teardown/19493) may have some useful information to you.